# How to capture previous value of same cell in formula based excel through python code

Tags: python

I am for coding for trading when there is change in quantity and Transaction Type (Buy/Sell)
Let say, I want to buy 1 qty of Idea from formula based excel, but due to buy remain in cell till there is change in formula based cell, So, there is multiple Buy trades takes place in while loop in python. So, looking for the code that trigger trades only when there is change in quantity cell or change in transaction type (Buy/Sell) from previous value. Please note, There cell is constant which gives different quantity or Buy/Sell. Hence, Need to check the previous value in quantity and Transaction type and if there is change in quantity or in transaction type value as compared to previous value than only trade trigger.

Below is example for ready reference:
**stage 1:** **No trades as the respective cell is blank**
Exchange    / Symbol/ Quantity  / Price / Transaction Type
/        /           /      /
**Stage 2: 1st Buy Trades take place**
Exchange    / Symbol/ Quantity  / Price / Transaction Type
NSE /          IDEA /   **1 **/             1 / **buy**

**Stage 3: 2nd Buy Trades take place only when there is change in quantity from previous Quantity value**
Exchange    / Symbol/ Quantity  / Price / Transaction Type
NSE /          IDEA /   **2 **/             1 / **buy**

**Stage 4: 3rd Sell Trades take place only when there is change in transaction type from previous value**
Exchange    / Symbol/ Quantity  / Price / Transaction Type
NSE /          IDEA /   **1 **/             1 / **Sell**

Please help for solution for the same.
Regards,

I have tried Python coding for the same, but unable to find solution.
I am expecting for python coding solution for the same.
Hence, please help for the solution.
Regards,